# file upload in react.js using apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

i was trying to upload file to my apollo server but i can't upload any file and it does not throw any error but i receive only empty object in resolver and it works find when i use **GraphQL Client** like **Altair**

**output in server when using Altair Client**

```js
{
    filename: 'Copy of Massive Orange Summer Sale Animated-300x250px-MediumRectangle.png',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
}
```

**output in server when using @apollo/client package**

```js
{}
```

**client code**

[image: client code]

**server code**

[image: server code]

Comment: Please do not post images of code.

Comment: @peace please share code instead of image link

Answer (score 6):

Uploads are not supported in Apollo Client by default. If you want to enable them, you need to use `createUploadLink` from `apollo-upload-client` as shown [here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client#function-createuploadlink).

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink(),
});
```